# How do you get the upper right hand configure gear icon to show up on certain Views?

Tags: 7, views

I'm currently on the users page and its being loaded via the [admin_views module](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views), but the configure gear icon doesnt show up on this view. Do I have to do something to have it show up? It works on other views, but some of them doesnt show up and im not sure why. I'm also using the Seven Theme.

[image]

Comment: Is it in the output HTML, simply invisible? Or not there at all?

Comment: i checked the source for "contextual" to see if there was a section in there for the view, but its not there at all. so its some how disabled for some reason on Views pages that is using the Seven theme. Its working fine on my Omega theme.